# Hi, how can i send data from one linux kernel driver to a running thread in a second driver without using global object?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have two drivers namely driver1 and driver2. I want to send data(received from application) from driver1 to a kernel thread (which is in sleep when no data is being received) initialised in driver2 without using global data.

// function exported by driver2 and being called by driver1

```
int recieve_from_driver1(char *data){      
    printk("CHAR DRIVER2: data from driver1: %s\n",data);
    datasize= strlen(data);

    // DataFromDriver1 is global data being accessed by thread.
    DataFromDriver1=kzalloc(datasize,GFP_KERNEL);  
    memcpy(DataFromDriver1,data,datasize);

    printk("CHAR DRIVER2: data from driver1: %s\n",DataFromDriver1);
    event_present=1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&my_event);
    // waking up thread when data is received from driver1

}
```

// thread used for processing data

```
static int thread_function(void* data){    
    while(!kthread_should_stop ()){

            set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
            wait_event_interruptible(my_event,(event_present == 1));

            if(kthread_should_stop())
            return 1;     
            // thread accessing global data                                                                                                   
            printk("CHAR DRIVER2 :  in thread DataFromDriver1 %s\n",DataFromDriver1);

            CheckSumResult1= checksum(DataFromDriver1);
            CheckSumResult2= checksumData(DataFromDriver1,strlen(DataFromDriver1));

            printk("CHAR DRIVER2 : in Thread CheckSumResult1= %d CheckSumResult2= %d \n",CheckSumResult1,CheckSumResult2);

              __set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
            event_present=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

56,17         19%

Comment: Driver, which holds data, needs to provide an API to allow consumers for it. When you get data in it, you should go through subscribers and inform them that data came in. Thus, linked list with accompanying mutex to maintain subscribers and data structure which holds data and some task related stuff, usually workqueue.